# Creating a rule that moves all incoming mail to deleted items or perm. Delete?

Tags: outlook

I am trying to create a rule that will move all incoming mail to deleted items or if possible delete them permenately.

Is anything such as this possible...I believe wildcards are not allowed in Outlook 2010.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Or maybe delete after a day?

Comment: A day has passed. Probably time to delete.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a rule in Outlook and assign a VBA macro sub to run. The macro sub should be in the following format:

```
public sub Test(mail as MailItem)
   ' do whatever you need
end sub
```

The mail object represents the incoming email message. You can use the [Move](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860683(v=office.15).aspx) method to move the message to another folder. The [Delete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863343(v=office.15).aspx) method can be used to delete it. The Delete method moves the item from the containing folder to the Deleted Items folder. If the containing folder is the Deleted Items folder, the Delete method removes the item permanently.